# How to Double Click in an automated way On macOS Ventura

Tags: macos, applescript, automation

I've been doing a pretty significant amount of research, and have tried asking a slightly less straightforward question on here before, but this time i want to explicitly ask about what I'm stuck on; how can one automate a double click on a macOS machine?

I know about clickclick, these machines are ephemeral and it would be better if i didnt have to install anything extra.

I know about appium's mac2 driver, and again, you have to install things for it to work.

You can't seem to double click with applescript, it doesnt appear to register as a double click, does anyone have a counter example?

I need the solution to work accross version of macOS, ill be testing on Monterey and Ventura.

EDIT regarding the other answers to this!: the comments in that question state it cant be done, and also that answer is from 2014.

Thanks

Comment: You can, it is just that AppleScript is not the tool for it.  Check out the [cliclick source](https://github.com/BlueM/cliclick) to see what is involved.